# Set Validation.Error property for controls at runtime

Tags: wpf, vb.net, validation

I have a method that should be called whenever a control has validation error.

I can do this using xaml by specifying the property `Validation.error="Method_Name"`

but how can I set this property for a dynamically created control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation.Error is an attached event, so to add a handler in code-behind, you have to use this syntax:

```
MyControl.AddHandler(Validation.ErrorEvent, New RoutedEventHandler(AddressOf MyEventHandler))
```

where MyEventHandler is just like any other WPF event handler:

```
Private Sub MyEventHandler(sender as object, e as RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim args as ValidationErrorEventArgs = DirectCast(e, ValidationErrorEventArgs)
    'Do stuff
End Sub
```